# python3 requests 400 Bad Request

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to login to webpage with requests but I'm getting this reason (400 Bad Request)

What I'm trying is :

First thing with Google Chrome inspect :

[1img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opqKi.png)

[2img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLtxo.png)

My Code :

```
import requests

from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)


headers = {
    "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0",
    "Referer": "https://doit.voicemail.centurylink.net/login",
}


data = {
    "DirectoryNumber": "1234567890",
    "Password": "1234567890",
    "next": "/"
}

with requests.Session() as c:

    response = c.post(url='https://doit.voicemail.centurylink.net/login',
        headers=headers,
        data=data,
        verify=False)

    print(response.history, response.url, response.status_code, response.reason)
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: Maybe you have to send JSON ? use json=data instead of data=data for this purpose

Comment: @D.Peter I also try (json=data) but same thing. 400 Bad Request

Answer (score 1):

I went on your website and found that maybe the way you need to send the data is :

```
data = MultipartEncoder(
    fields=(
            ('DirectoryNumber', '1234567890'), 
            ('Password', '1234567890'),
            ('next', '/')
           )
    )

with requests.Session() as c:

    response = c.post(url='https://doit.voicemail.centurylink.net/login',
        headers=headers,
        data=data,
        verify=False)
```

and maybe it's not 'next' but 'redirectTo' that you have to specify

Comment: Error : raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <MultipartEncoder: {'Password': '1234567890', 'DirectoryNumber': '1234567890'}> is not JSON serializable

Comment: now I replace : next with redirectTo.
now I'm getting new error : [<Response [302]>] https://doit.voicemail.centurylink.net/?error=invalidParameters 200 OK

I use : data = {
 "DirectoryNumber": "123456789",
 "Password": "123456789",
 "redirectTo": ""
}

Comment: It's maybe caus because of invalid identifiers to your platform, I don't know